# Azure Data Factory sFTP Keep Connection Open

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've created a pipeline in Data Factory that pulls several files from an sFTP server and places the data into Azure SQL Server Database tables.

Everything works fine in DF, but my sFTP server only allows 8 concurrent connections and 16 connections per minute. Data Factory is exceeding that limit because I believe it is disconnecting and reconnecting for each file.

I see in [Azure **FTP** Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ftp/) there is an option called `Close connection after request completion`. Will this alleviate my errors? Is there a similar flag for **sFTP** in Data Factory?

Answer (score 0):

The link that you shared is for a connector that is available only for Microsoft Flow, Power Apps and Logic Apps.

One way to achieve your intent is by using a custom activity in which you can write .NET code to configure and manage your SFTP connections. To read more about custom activities, please refer [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity).

Answer (score 0):

To whom still suffering this.
We can limit the max connections in ADF, please see below screenshot.
[image: SFTP connection limit]